# System Status Notice about Timestamps and Timezones

Tags: wordpress, status

I've update my CiviCRM from 4.7.24 to 4.7.29 (my CiviCRM system on WordPress), everything seems ok but I have System Status Notice:

Timestamps and Timezones

This MySQL database stores certain fields with data-type "DATETIME". To improve timezone support, you may want to change these from "DATETIME" to "TIMESTAMP".

civicrm_subscription_history.date (New sites default to TIMESTAMP in v4.7.27+) [CRM-21157] (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21157)

Changing should improve data-quality for organizations working in multiple timezones. However, if you do change, then you may need to re-test any customizations or processes that reference these fields. Changing is suggested but not required.

For further discussion, please visit https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.doctorwhen

How can I do to pass this notice?

Comment: Here is the documentation for this https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.doctorwhen/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank for reply. I've uploaded doctorwhen extension and active, but I still don't know how to Usage (Web) because I'm still not familiar with CLI or PHP. I run link https://mywebsiteadress.com/civicrm/doctorwhen?reset=1 but not find this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found link go to Doctorw Wen in CiviCRM (WordPress version) by go to Administrator Menu and fix the notice "Timestamps and Timezones", Thanks!

[image: Menu go to Doctor When]

Answer (score 0):

Applying the patches mentioned in the commits information [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21157?devStatusDetailDialog=repository) will fix your problem for civicrm_subscription_history.date column.